# How to push to remote repo after rebase without all previous added commit history?

Tags: git, push, rebase, git-merge-conflict

I'm not good at git yet. I want to ask you, how the rebase with remote repo should be made.

I mean, I have **main** branch (remote) and I also have branch eg. **my_branch** (local). When PR for merging **my_branch** to **main** was open, there was few more commits added to **main** that causes **conflicts on my_branch**.

So, I always:

- update main branch
- checkout my_branch
- rebase my_branch with main
- resolve conflicts
- pull changes
- commit
- push to remote main

But, it creates in the PR weird commit history and also adding these to my PR. I don't want it. I would like to rebase my_branch with main, push it to the remote repo and won't see these commits that was added to main when my PR was open for a while.

How can I change it? I know that there is a way, but I don't understand it correctly. Anyone can explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally I recommend not to use `git pull`. It does two things (`git fetch` and `git merge`) and especially for beginners it is easier to do those two steps one by one.

Comment: I don't see why you would pull (fetch and merge) after you resolved the conflicts. Does omitting this step already solve your issue?

Comment: Ok, so I go to the main branch, run git fetch to update repository, checkout my branch. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation where I have a branch `my_branch` out of which I later want to make a pull-request I usually follow this workflow:

- fetch
- if the remote `main` has new commits:

  - rebase my local `my_branch` onto the remote `main`, resolving conflicts if they appear
- add some commits to `my_branch`
- push `my_branch` (using `--force-with-lease` if I have already pushed before)

Now my work is present in the remote and I can create a pull request out of that branch or just have it sitting there for a while as a backup.